# Translating "Makes sense"

Tags: traducción

How would the following be translated into Spanish:

> "The football costs 18 dollars"
>
> "Oh, that makes sense"

Or just "Makes sense"

Comment: "Oh, eso tiene sentido" o "tiene razon" o algo asi.

Comment: Could you attempt to translate it first? The rules of this site encourage users to try to translate themselves, and be corrected and helped from the community rather than just asking for plain translations.

Comment: Please, do try to translate it for yourself to avoid the question being closed as off-topic. That said, I think the translation varies depending on the context. If you have asked the price of the football in a shop and with _that makes sense_ you mean _it's a fair price_, I would adapt (not translate) it as _me parece justo_ or _me parece bien_. I consider this a case in which the translation can't be word by word, and what you really need to translate is what the speaker really meant with it. If you provide a context and a translation attempt, this could be a good question.

Answer (score 5):

The most accurate translation for **makes sense** is **tiene sentido**.

The same happens with the well known **it has to do with**, translated as **tiene que ver con**.